# Problems with IronPython Studio and PictureBox

Tags: ironpython-studio

Right, so I'm having a go at Iron Python Studio as I'm quite familiar with VS2005 and want to try Python with an integrated GUI designer. But as soon as I add a PictureBox I'm in trouble. When running the project I get complaints about BeginInit and soon enough the form designer stops working.
Is this because I'm running .NET 3.5 or some other compatibility issue? Couldn't find anything at the [Iron Python Studio site](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPythonStudio)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. What you can do is manually remove the BeginInit() and EndInit() calls, it should work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [IronPython Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ironpython/) on MSDN? You could probably drill down from there and find a definitive answer. If you do, be sure you update your question here!